# PHP Namespaces autoloading, need composer?

Tags: php, namespaces

When using PHP namespaces do i need to use composer or does PHP have built in functionality to resolve namespaces/folders?

I think the use of composer makes we do not have to use require and such to import classes from subdirectoeries, is that assumption right?

Regards

Comment: Composer provides a default autoloader. Without it, you will need to provide your own.

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
The third comment there shows, how to autoload with namespaces

Comment: I think the comment mentioned by Sindhara is at this permalink:
https://www.php.net/language.oop5.autoload#120258